# Need help creating macro converting rows to sheets from Yes and No matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for converting my Yes & No matrix to a separate sheet tabs in workbook of excel with help of Macro in VBA.

So I have B1 to Z1 columns named with equipment and column A2 to A50 named with tests. The area B2 to Z50 is filled with Y and N based on the test and the requirement of equipment.

What I am looking is if there is any way I can use Macro to do split the data in sheets with Equipment names and each sheet will contain name of only those tests which are marked Y in the matrix.

Example Matrix

[image]

I am new to VBA, had done couple of tries by looking it resources available on intermate but no luck so far. Looking fwd for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitEq()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dataArea As Range, rng As Range, cl As Range
    
    Const DATA_SHEET_NAME = "DataSheet" ' DataSheet into Worksheets("DataSheet") with the name of your own worksheet with data
    Const ANCHOR = "H16" 'cell address within data range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' speed up script working
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DATA_SHEET_NAME)
        Set dataArea = .Range(ANCHOR).CurrentRegion
        
        For Each cl In Intersect(dataArea(1).EntireRow, .UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(0, 1)) ' skip rows names column
            
            dataArea.AutoFilter   ' set initial filter or reset previous filter
            dataArea.AutoFilter Field:=cl.Column - dataArea(1).Column + 1, Criteria1:="Y"
            
            ' select only visible cells after filter apply and get rows names at rows where these cells are is
            Set rng = Intersect( _
                Intersect(cl.EntireColumn, .UsedRange) _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                .EntireRow, .Columns(dataArea(1).Column))
            
            If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then  ' rng contains not only header
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                ws.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets( _
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) ' move the ws to the end
                ws.Name = cl    ' set the ws name
                rng.Copy ws.Range("A1")
            End If
        Next
        .AutoFilterMode = False     ' switch off the filter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Hey , thanks a lot but having issue with this line: "With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")"

Getting error of :
Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: @Rockycool As you see on screenshots, my worksheet named `DataSheet`. Replace `DataSheet` into `Worksheets("DataSheet")` with the name of your own worksheet with data.

Comment: Oh great. Anyway to shift this? I mean if I want to change the range of table from (A1 to Z50) to Say (J1 to  AH50). How I can do that

Comment: In this code "anchor" to data range is `Set dataArea = .Range("B1").CurrentRegion`. Try `Set dataArea = .Range("K1").CurrentRegion` for shifted table. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion

Comment: ...and replace `.Columns(1)` in `Set rng = Intersect(...` with `.Columns(10)` because number of column J is 10

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It does put filter at J1 with this but the sheet name still comes from B1. And I get error: "Runtime error 1004: Method "Name"  of object "_Worksheet" failed on this line: ws.Name = cl    ' set the ws name

Comment: @Rockycool See my previous post about `.Columns(10)`

Comment: Yes, even with that, .Columns (10) still facing it

Comment: I changed the code slightly - see above, now only the sheet name and cell address need to be configured - see `CONST`. This code worked on a table that starts at H16

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance. When I move my table from A1 and make changes in above code, it works flawlessly. But if I move it from say J1 , and if there is other data in A to I columns, this code throws 1004 error on line: dataArea.AutoFilter Field:=cl.Column - dataArea(1).Column + 1, Criteria1:="Y"

Comment: @Rockycool The example code was written as one way of solving your original question. If you want to change something in the problem statement and adapt the code yourself, it is advisable to learn more about VBA, the Excel object model and debugging techniques

Comment: okay, Thanks. Unfortunately I was not aware that having filled cell before the selected range, Excel treats it differently. I tried defining range in your suggested code but if there is any single cell filled outside of this range, the code throws 1004. Not able to fix it.